# Что означает слово "Ярб"?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, литература

"Ярб бежал впереди, сгоняя с дороги птиц" — "Мёртвые души", Гоголь (том II глава IV). Кто такой *Ярб*?

Я полагаю, это "коренной" конь из запряжённых в пролётку, средний в тройке.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Что означает слово “ярб”?

Кличка собаки, там же с заглавной буквы везде.

> Между тем вошел в комнату сам Платонов, красавец, стройного роста, с
>   светло-русыми блестящими волосами, завива<вшимися в> кудри. Гремя
>   медным ошейником, мордатый пес, собака-страшилище, именем Ярб, вошел
>   вослед за ним.

[Гоголь Николай, Глава III - Том 7. Мертвые души. Том 2 | e-reading.club](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/99068/3/Gogol%27_07_Tom_7._Mertvye_dushi._Tom_2.html)

> "коренной" конь из запряжённых в пролётку, средний в тройке.

Да. Коренной или коренник - центральная лошадь, по бокам - пристяжные. Каждая только в одном месте была, не путали никогда.